# List of multiple types using generic types in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have created a class that can keep list of 2 types: TPersonA and TPersonB (they have difference in one property). Works flawlessly, but problems start when i want to edit specific fields, because they are different depending on the type.

```cs
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
        where T : class, IEntity<int>, IPerson
    {
        protected static List<T> _dataBase = new List<T>();
        ...
        public void Edit(T entity)
        {
            var toEdit = _dataBase.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
            toEdit.Id = entity.Id;
            toEdit.FirstName = entity.FirstName;
            toEdit.LastName = entity.FirstName;
            toEdit.DateOfBirth = entity.DateOfBirth;
            toEdit.Section = entity.Section;

            switch (entity)
            {
                case TPersonA a:
                    toEdit.Specialization = entity.Specialization;
                    break;
                case TPersonB b:
                    toEdit.AIndex = entity.AIndex;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Current code doesn't work, compiler has no idea what Specialization and AIndex is, which is understandable, because TPersonA and B are lower in hierarchy than basic class TPerson. But when i add IPersonA and IPersonB to constraints my code in Main will no longer work.

```cs
IRepository<TPerson> repository = new Repository<TPerson>();
```

Which is also kind of understandable. Because TPerson is higher in hierarchy and it can't be converted to A or B. 
How can i fix it? I tried to bypass it by creating auxiliary class that will handle all operations that can't be done with generic types, but then i lack access to _dataBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast `entity` to same class:

```
switch (entity)
{
    case TPersonA a when toEdit is TPersonA castedEntity:
        castedEntity.Specialization = a.Specialization;
        break;
    case TPersonB b when toEdit is TPersonB castedEntity:
        castedEntity.AIndex = b.AIndex;
        break;
}
```

But I would not recommend to do so. It's better to have two different repositories for `TPersonA` and `TPersonB` even though their objects are saved to same table.

Comment: It actually works fine, i mean no errors. But i think entity should be changed to toEdit. I will try it in practice now.

Comment: Accepting your answer, while i'm not sure is it the best solution (since i'm still learning) it actually works and i can understand why. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, you're right it should be toEdit instead of entity.